# WebAPI GetRouteData works in self host, fails on web host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have JSON data that is being POSTed which refers to other resources by their full URL, like this:

```
{
    jobItems : [
        "http://example.com/item/3",
        "http://example.com/item/5" 
    ]
}
```

In my WebAPI controller, I parse these URLs by reusing the corresponding route:

```
private static IHttpRouteData ParseLink(
    this ApiController controller,
    string routeName,
    Uri uri)
{
    var fakeRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
    string virtualPathRoot = controller.Configuration.VirtualPathRoot;
    var route = controller.Configuration.Routes[routeName];
    return route.GetRouteData(virtualPathRoot, fakeRequest);
}
```

The above works fine in a stand-alone self-hosted WebAPI deployment. However, when I deploy my WebAPI controllers in an ASP.NET MVC4 application on a web host (IIS) , GetRouteData throws the following exception:

```
System.NotImplementedException
   at System.Web.HttpContextBase.get_Items()
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpContextBaseExtensions.GetHttpRequestMessage(HttpContextBase context)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute.ProcessConstraint(HttpContextBase httpContext, Object constraint, String parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
   at System.Web.Routing.Route.ProcessConstraints(HttpContextBase httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
   at System.Web.Routing.Route.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HostedHttpRoute.GetRouteData(String rootVirtualPath, HttpRequestMessage request)
```

What's going wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to fix it:

```
private static IHttpRouteData ParseLink(this ApiController controller, Uri uri)
{
    var fakeRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);

    return controller.Configuration.Routes.GetRouteData(fakeRequest);
}
```

Comment: This is a bit simpler, but it still throws the same exception.

Comment: hmm...i actually did try myself in webhost scenario and this worked...which version of Web API are you using? (like which version of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` nuget package are you using?)

Comment: `<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />`

Comment: Ok, i tried on the version `4.0.30506.0`...may be this was a bug in the version you are using...probably you should update it to the above version or even the latest version of Web API which is 5.0

Comment: I got the same exception for `4.0.30506.0`. But at least now I know that is something special about my use case.

Comment: I figured out what the difference was. I have a custom `IHttpRouteConstraint` on my WebAPI routes. Adding a simple constraint (e.g. that implements `Match` by always returning true) to the route in 'WebApiConfig` in the WebAPI project template is sufficient to reproduce the problem.